# c++ function "size_t PASCAL"

Tags: c++, function, hook, size-t

I was looking at some code , what does this type of function means ?

```
size_t PASCAL OnNewSendto( some param , some param  )
```

Comment: I'm assuming [this is the context](http://pastebin.com/wTNwrPw7) for OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

```
size_t PASCAL OnNewSendto(...)
```

- `size_t` is the return value type.
- `PASCAL` is a macro that represents a calling convention. Exactly what the macro expands to depends on your platform, and the headers you include. Quite possibly it expands to nothing, or to `__stdcall`.
- `OnNewSendto` is the function name.

The Pascal calling convention is, nowadays, a historic relic. It doesn't exist on modern platforms and is a hangover from the 16 bit days. You'd have to show more context for us to know what the macro expands to. Of course, you can easily run the code through your pre-processor to find that out.

On my system, given this input,

```
#include <Windows.h>
int PASCAL foo();
```

the pre-processor emits:

```
int foo();
```

So, for this system at least, `PASCAL` expands to nothing.

But if you compiled on a different platform, say an ancient 16 bit platform, then you could expect a different expansion.

Comment: `PASCAL` *most likely* expands to some calling convention, but maybe nothing. This usually depends on the compiler, configure flags and the environment.

Comment: In the code i'm referring, it is hooking 'sendto' of wsock32.dll. so here pascal is a must ? and size_t is exactly what ? i mean can you give a simple example of function with that return value type.

Comment: Only you know for sure what PASCAL is in your code. We can only presume it's the macro from the Windows header file. As for size_t, it is well covered in every textbook. Have you used websearch yet?